# How to pass an array from a query inside a foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following query that will bring all Auth user friends :

```
$usrusrmembs = DB::table('usrusrs')
                    ->where('accepted', 1)
                    ->where('user_id', $u_id)
                    ->orwhere('friend_id', $u_id)                   
                    ->pluck('friend_id', 'user_id');
```

Next is a foreach to loop the ids received from the above query, get the posts of all Ids, and then sending the result to a blade :

```
foreach($usrusrmembs as $key => $val){

       $rec_users = ($key == $u_id) ? $val : $key;  

      $f_usrs_psts = DB::table('posts')      
            ->where('posts.user_id', $rec_users)
            ->get();

                                      }

return view('updates', ['f_posts' => $f_usrs_psts] );
```

The output in the blade shows only posts of one friend , while ignores the others. I feel there is a problem in the posts query, where it only sends to the blade the last processed ID. If this is the problem, then how can I solve it ?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you want to avoid executing queries within a loop. For example, if `$usrusrmembs` contains 1000 values, you are making 1000 calls to your database. I would rework your initial query to obtain all of the results you require in a single call. Also, where have you defined `$f_usrs_psts`?

Comment: You get only 1 result because you overwrite the `$f_usrs_psts` variable in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where Laravel really shines.  Take advantage of the relationships and do this all in one query with eager loading.  I don't know what your model relations are, but something like this:

```
$usrusrmembs = \App\UserUserModel::where('accepted', 1)
                ->where('user_id', $u_id)
                ->orwhere('friend_id', $u_id)                   
                ->with('posts')
                ->get();
```

If you want more control, you can use a combination of closures and `whereHas`, but this above should get you close.  Then, in your view you can loop on the posts for each:

```
  @foreach($usrusrmembs as $usr)
      echo $usr-name // etc
      @foreach ($usr->posts as $post)
          echo $post->whatever
      @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

This is not going to give you exactly what you need, but the idea should help you to work through it and you can skip the whole n+1 issue by removing the foreach loop in your controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. I'm trying to do this solution, but I received (Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()). I don't have a relation between posts and usrusr models, as usrusr is the friendship table. The User table is related to both tables though.

Comment: Sounds like you may wish to rethink your architecture a little bit.  I might suggest you make **usrusr** model an extension of **User** model and then the posts would follow.  Or, if **usrusr** is the same table as **User**, just add `posts` as a relation on **usrusr** .  Either way, I think it will make your life much easier to have that relationship - you can eager load as well as simply call the relation in your view like in my answer :)